# How to debug "Malformed or Illegal request" when using Ansible Google Cloud module?

Tags: ansible, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using Ansible's [backend service](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/gcp_backend_service_module.html) module for GCE. Here is the task that I am running

```
- name: Create BES with extended backend parameters
  gcp_backend_service:
    service_account_email: "111111111-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
    credentials_file: "/home/aditya/gce-default.json"
    project_id: "logical-bolt-1111"
    backend_service_name: service1
    backends:
    - instance_group: ansible-mig-example
      zone: us-west1-c
    healthchecks:
    - name: my-healthcheck
    port_name: http
    state: present
    timeout: 60
```

This task fails with a traceback:

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_Yj_kyP/ansible_module_gcp_backend_service.py", line 409, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/ansible_Yj_kyP/ansible_module_gcp_backend_service.py", line 395, in main
    params)
  File "/tmp/ansible_Yj_kyP/ansible_module_gcp_backend_service.py", line 302, in create_backend_service
    hc = get_healthcheck(gce, hc_name)
  File "/tmp/ansible_Yj_kyP/ansible_module_gcp_backend_service.py", line 276, in get_healthcheck
    return gce.ex_get_healthcheck(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libcloud/compute/drivers/gce.py", line 6584, in ex_get_healthcheck
    response = self.connection.request(request, method='GET').object
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libcloud/compute/drivers/gce.py", line 120, in request
    response = super(GCEConnection, self).request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libcloud/common/google.py", line 806, in request
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libcloud/common/base.py", line 871, in request
    response = responseCls(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libcloud/common/base.py", line 182, in __init__
    self.object = self.parse_body()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libcloud/common/google.py", line 286, in parse_body
    raise InvalidRequestError(message, self.status, code)
libcloud.common.google.InvalidRequestError: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\n  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">\n  <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>\n  <style>\n    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}\n  </style>\n  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>\n  <p><b>400.</b> <ins>That\xe2\x80\x99s an error.</ins>\n  <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>That\xe2\x80\x99s all we know.</ins>'
```

This is almost identical to the example listed on the module page and I am not able to get more details on why this is failing. How should I go on to debug this?

Comment: No real answer but when I last encountered this error it was because of a malformed (non-string) variable which I exanded via {{ variable }}. Thus I'd recommend to check any data for spelling mistakes and wrong expansions.